# Angular : Wait for an Observable to finish before returning the value

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a method which needs to return an Observable. This observable is then fed to a third party component as input. We can not modify the third party component.

The problem that I am facing here while returning the desired observable is that I need to perform some computation on the result and this computation is dependent on another service call (_transService.getTransactions) which can only be executed after first service call.

How can I modify the the result of first service call before returning it as observable (Observable < searchResult > ).

Currently in the code below it cannot wait for call to finish and return empty data.

```
public search(): Observable<Response<ListDetail>> {
  let searchResult: Response<ListDetail>;

  let gridData: ListDetail[] = [];
  this.post(`search`)
    .pipe(
      filter((response: Response<ListDetail>): boolean => response && response.status === 'Success'),
      mergeMap(
        (res: Response<ListDetail>): Observable<Response<Transactions[]>> => {
          searchResult = res;
          gridData = res.content.items;
          const ids = res.content.items.map((result: ListDetail) => result.id);
          return this._transService.getTransactions(ids);
        }
      )
    )
    .subscribe((res: Response<Transactions[]>) => {
      const transactionsList = res.content;
      gridData.forEach((item: ListDetail) => {
        item.transactions = [];
        transactionsList.forEach((result: Transactions) => {
          const transactions = result?.transactions;
          transactions.forEach((transaction: Transaction) => {
            if (transaction.parentId === 0) {
              item.transactions.push(transaction);
              if (transaction.transactionType === 'CASH') {
                if (!item.cashAmount) {
                  item.cashAmount = 0;
                }
                item.cashAmount+= transaction.amount;
              }              }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  return of(searchResult);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
public search(): Observable<Response<ListDetail>> {
  let searchResult: Response<ListDetail>;
  return new Observable<Response<ListDetail>>(observer => {

    let gridData: ListDetail[] = [];
    this.post(`search`)
      .pipe(
        filter((response: Response<ListDetail>): boolean => response && response.status === 'Success'),
        mergeMap(
          (res: Response<ListDetail>): Observable<Response<Transactions[]>> => {
            searchResult = res;
            gridData = res.content.items;
            const ids = res.content.items.map((result: ListDetail) => result.id);
            return this._transService.getTransactions(ids);
          }
        )
      )
      .subscribe((res: Response<Transactions[]>) => {
        const transactionsList = res.content;
        gridData.forEach((item: ListDetail) => {
          item.transactions = [];
          transactionsList.forEach((result: Transactions) => {
            const transactions = result?.transactions;
            transactions.forEach((transaction: Transaction) => {
              if (transaction.parentId === 0) {
                item.transactions.push(transaction);
                if (transaction.transactionType === 'CASH') {
                  if (!item.cashAmount) {
                    item.cashAmount = 0;
                  }
                  item.cashAmount+= transaction.amount;
                }
              }
            });
          });
        });
        
        observer.next(searchResult);
        observer.complete();
        
      });
  
  });


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use tap:

```
public search(): Observable<Response<ListDetail>> {
  return new Observable<Response<ListDetail>>(observer => {

    let gridData: ListDetail[] = [];
    this.post(`search`)
      .pipe(
        filter((response: Response<ListDetail>): boolean => response && response.status === 'Success'),
        tap( res => { 
          observer.next(res);
          observer.complete();
        }),
        mergeMap(
          (res: Response<ListDetail>): Observable<Response<Transactions[]>> => {
            searchResult = res;
            gridData = res.content.items;
            const ids = res.content.items.map((result: ListDetail) => result.id);
            return this._transService.getTransactions(ids);
        }
        )
      )
      .subscribe((res: Response<Transactions[]>) => {
        const transactionsList = res.content;
        gridData.forEach((item: ListDetail) => {
          item.transactions = [];
          transactionsList.forEach((result: Transactions) => {
            const transactions = result?.transactions;
            transactions.forEach((transaction: Transaction) => {
              if (transaction.parentId === 0) {
                item.transactions.push(transaction);
                if (transaction.transactionType === 'CASH') {
                  if (!item.cashAmount) {
                    item.cashAmount = 0;
                  }
                  item.cashAmount+= transaction.amount;
                }
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
  });
}
```